# Apt-get update does not work because of openSUSE's repo

Tags: bash, opensuse

I have a small problem, I shall like installing ruby one rails on my BONE (BLINUX) but for it I should make the order:
 - sudo apt-get update (to make a small update)
 but my system so answers me :
[image: terminal with error's link]

Thanks for your answer ^^

Comment: ans it's not only for that command, i have the same result for each command with "apt-get" ans the reason of the error is the openSUSE's repo online please help me ^^

Comment: BONE = OS sorry

Comment: Can't make out the attachment

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to put an other image ^^' I searching

Comment: there is the attachement : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdnCf.png

Answer (score 1):

openSUSE does not use apt-get, it uses zypper. apt-get is a system-wide wrapper for zypper, see `apt-get --version`.

With that out of the way, let's get to your real problem.
You are not using an official openSUSE product. You are using "blinux", a product that is based on openSUSE with some custom configurations. One of the configurations leads to your problem.

The error that zypper prints out means there is a problem with the "openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Oss" repo. That one points to https://pkg.blinux.fr/opensuse/distribution/tumbleweed/repo/oss. That repo is not maintained by openSUSE but by blinux, they have to fix your problem unless you change to official openSUSE repos.

Just edit your repos in /etc/zypp/repos.d/ and change to URLs.
The base URL for Tumbleweed is http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/ where you find oss/ non-ss/ debug/ and the src-*/ repos.

Once you have the correct repos, run `zypper ref && zypper dup --allow-vendor-change` to update to official versions.